# c# - Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to communicate with an API using the ASP.NET MVC standard, I'm currently getting user data from a form but when I try to call the API I always get a "Bad Request" return.
Analyzing the return logs, I checked that the body of my request is sent correctly with the JSON payload but even then they return me that my Content-Length equals zero and that the transfer encoding was chunked.
Has anyone ever had a similar situation?

Below is my request

```
 public async Task CreateTransaction(Order order)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ENDPOINT);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HEADER1);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HEADER2);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("RESOURCE", order);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 



        }

    }
```

Comment: HttpClient should be static as stated in MSDN.

Comment: Further to eocron, you shouldn't have HttpClient in a using statement. See: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Thanks for both guidelines, I've fixed these two points. 
Unfortunately the main issue remains :(